# Friction energy dissipation calculation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, power

In a moving block, a **variable** force pushes it. Friction is acting against the movement.

Below equation specify the amount of energy could be used to give motion: $$
E_1 = \int F_T(t)  .v(t) .dt 
$$

However, because of friction,energy used to give motion gets smaller:

$$
E_2= \int [F_T(t)-F_R].v(t).dt 
$$

Can I assume E2 as energy used to give motion and E3 as dissipated energy due to the friction?
$$
E_3=\int F_R(t).v(t).dt
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $F_R$ to be the frictional force then yes you can split up the energy as you suggest. Your $E_2$ will be the change in the kinetic energy of the object and the $E_3$ will be the energy lost due to friction.